# Need an algorithm to map co-ordinates of a point in images with different dimensions

Tags: java, image-processing

I am stuck with a problem in my current project. I have 2 copies of same image say image1.tiff and image2.tiff but of different dimensions(Different pixel and DPIs). Suppose a point in image1.tiff lies at co-ordinates (x,y) ,I need to find the co-ordinates of the same point in image2.tiff. I have tried a lot to think of an algorithm. Requesting your help for this ..

Comment: In theory you should just need to scale the x/y coordinates.  So if the image A is 50% larger then image B, then any point in A is 50% smaller on B (or in this, half)...nb- My math is crap so I apologize if the implementation is wrong, but the theory should be correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AffineTransformOp` for this.

As an example:

```
BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(400, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

double sx = img2.getWidth() / (double) img1.getWidth();
double sy = img2.getHeight() / (double) img1.getHeight();

AffineTransformOp xform = 
        new AffineTransformOp(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(sx, sy), null);
Point srcPt = new Point(7, 49);
Point dstPoint = (Point) xform.getPoint2D(srcPt, new Point());

System.err.println("srcPt: " + srcPt);
System.err.println("dstPoint: " + dstPoint);
```

Will print:

```
srcPt: java.awt.Point[x=7,y=49]
dstPoint: java.awt.Point[x=14,y=98]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach:

```
double image1_to_image2 = image2.width()/image1.width();
double image2_to_image1 = image1.width()/image2.width();
```

If you have `x1` and `y1` as coordinates for the first image, you can calculate the corresponding location for the second image as follows:

```
int x2 = x1 * image1_to_image2;
int y2 = y1 * image1_to_image2;
```

If your images have a different aspect ratio, you will need to calculate scaling factors for the height separately.

The basic idea behind the approach is, that you map the coordinates of the images to the interval `i_1 = [0;1]` by dividing by the width (assuming the width is the larger dimension, but it does not matter if it is smaller than the height). By multiplying the scaled coordinate with the width of the second image, you map the coordinate back to the interval `i_2 = [0; x_1 * width_2]` which is at most the width of the second image.